# "spawn C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell ENOENT" error while running npm start

Tags: javascript, reactjs, powershell, npm

When ever I try to execute npm start, this is what happens. I think there is some issue with powershell and not with npm because npm starts the development server. BTW I created basic react app using npx create-react-app. I checked, powershell file is there in the specified location and it is working as well. Guild me what should I do in order to resolve the error.

```
events.js:353
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
Error: spawn C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell ENOENT
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:269:19)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:467:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:467:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell',
  path: 'C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell',
  spawnargs: [
    '-NoProfile',
    '-NonInteractive',
    '–ExecutionPolicy',
    'Bypass',
    '-EncodedCommand',
    'UwB0AGEAcgB0ACAAIgBoAHQAdABwADoALwAvAGwAbwBjAGEAbABoAG8AcwB0ADoAMwAwADAAMAAiAA=='
  ]
}
```

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Try running the app from a terminal (cmd.exe)

Comment: I am running it in cmd.exe only

Comment: Please paste the relevant messages as text as well so they can be searched for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after trying everything and looking for the error on every possible website. I still wasn't able to resolve the error. Then I personally talked to someone regarding the error and he suggested me to run it in Windows Sub-system for Linux (WSL). I exactly did that and installed WSL with Linux 20.04 LTS. Now I am using Unix terminal to create the react app. It isn't the best solution for the problem, but yeah it does work and saves a lot of time!

Answer (score 5):

I faced with a same problem on Windows 10.
And solution was a pretty simple - just run your commands in git bush console.

Comment: After a few hours of searching the internet, this solution actually worked, thank you!

Comment: I just spent hours installing different node versions and reinstalling until I tried this. And it WORKED!?!? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:(reason of the error)

go to  C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0 and then you will not be found powershell.exe file that folder.

Step 2: (solution of the error)

download powershell.exe file online or just copy and paste this file in C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0

https://www.exefiles.com/en/exe/powershell-exe/  - To download powershell.exe file online

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this error occurs , I sated paths and all but nothing it worked.
**But I have one solution**

simply write your code in git bash .
you can also change your vs code terminal to git bash.
Link to change = " https://blog.danielpadua.dev/posts/git-bash-with-vscode/ ".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on WSL and resolved by modifying my /etc/wsl.conf

wsl.conf that caused the error (apparently by modifying the path to powershell.exe into something wrong):

```
[network] 
generateResolvConf = false 
mount -t drvfs C: /mnt/c 
root = / 
options = metadata
```

wsl.conf that works:

```
[network] 
generateResolvConf = false
```

Some background for this error causing wsl.conf:

I had issues accessing /mnt/c from my WSL and had changed the wsl.conf originally into the error causing one. As instructed here: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1864#issuecomment-506005637